# How to convert given seconds to hours minutes seconds format in php in custom way?

Tags: php, time, date-conversion

I will get random number of seconds the number may greater than 86400 which is greater than 24hours (when converts to hours) so php `gmdate()` won't get my required output. So I created the following code.

```
$ts = mt_rand(36000,99999); 
echo floor($ts/3600)."Hr ".floor(($ts/3600 - floor($ts/3600))*60)."min ".round(((($ts/3600 - floor($ts/3600))*60) - floor(($ts/3600 - floor($ts/3600))*60))*60)."sec";
```

I am getting the output like **22Hr 29min 4sec** for **$ts = 80944;**
Everything is fine but for **$ts = 39540;** the output came is **10Hr 58min 60sec** here 60sec came which is wrong. it should get like **10Hr 59min 0sec.** What's wrong in my code?

Comment: working fine:- https://eval.in/714758

Comment: for `$ts = 99545;` i am getting **27Hr 39min 5sec** from my code but when i used `gmdate()` the output is **3:39:05** which is not correct for my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't break your code apart to find out what was wrong, but I believe this solves the problem.

```
$ts = mt_rand(36000,99999);

$h = floor($ts / 3600);
$m = floor(($ts - 3600 * $h) / 60);
$s = $ts - ($h * 3600) - ($m * 60);

echo $h . "Hr " . $m . "Min " . $s . "s";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo gmdate("H:i:s", 39540);
```

use this

Comment: Read the question.He said that he used it

Comment: It's working fine if the seconds value is less than 86400(i.e 24 hours). but i may get 30Hr 24min 30sec something like this. By using `gmdate()` i am not getting desired output. Understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code to check if the value of secs is 60, as It is already being caluculated due to round while calculating minutes

```
    $ts = 80944; //mt_rand(36000,99999); 

    echo floor($ts/3600)."Hr ". round(($ts/3600 - floor($ts/3600))*60)."min ";
    echo (round(((($ts/3600 - floor($ts/3600))*60) - floor(($ts/3600 - floor($ts/3600))*60))*60) == 60) ? '0' : round(((($ts/3600 - floor($ts/3600))*60) - floor(($ts/3600 - floor($ts/3600))*60))*60)."sec";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do it with a modulo calculation :

```
$secondsGiven = 1036899;
$outputSeconds = $secondsGiven % 60;
$minutes = ($secondsGiven-$outputSeconds) / 60 ;
$outputMinutes = $minutes % 60;
$hours = ($minutes - $outputMinutes) / 60;
$outputHours= $hours % 24;
$outputDays = $outputHours / 24;
echo $outputDays . 'Days ' . $outputHours . 'HR ' . $outputMinutes . 'min ' . $outputSeconds . 'sec';
```

this example would output : **12Days 0Hr 1min 39sec**